# Saga keeps making the same API call

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-saga

I am new to using Sagas. Can someone please help me understand why, on reload, my saga keeps making an API call? Here is my code.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { put, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import apiHelper from '../../utils/apiHelper';
import {getPicSumImages} from '../actions/action';
import {PicSumTypes} from '../actions/types';

function* loadPicSumImages(){
  try {
    const response = yield axios.get(apiHelper.getUsersApi(), apiHelper.getApiHeader());
    const data = yield response.data;
    yield put(getPicSumImages(data));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('FAILED API CALL');
  }
}

function* picSumSaga() {
  yield takeEvery(PicSumTypes.GetImages, loadPicSumImages);
}

export default picSumSaga;
```

Here is the file I am calling the sagas.

```
import React, { FC, useEffect } from 'react';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import {getPicSumImages} from '../../redux/actions/action';
import HomeView from './HomeView';

const HomeContainer: FC = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const data = useSelector(state => state?.picSum?.data);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPicSumImages(data));
  },[data, dispatch]);

  return <HomeView data={data} />;
};

export default HomeContainer;
```

Here is an image as well
[image]

Comment: can you show how you are calling `loadUsers `

Comment: Just updated the code. Thanks for responding.

Comment: My guess is it seems like every time the saga updates the data, your useEffect() gets called again since `data` is then updated.

Comment: I figured it out. the `dispatcher` is a dependency in useEffect so it kept getting called.

Comment: Unrelated but I think you want to wrap the `axios.get()` in a `call` effect.

Answer (score 0):

in your **actions** file, check and varify the types of actions "**loadPicSumImages**" and "**getPicSumImages**".

also in saga file "**yield takeEvery(PicSumTypes.GetImages, loadPicSumImages)**",
varify that "**GetImages**" is the right type for action "**loadPicSumImages**".